# Как посчитать коэффициент экспоненциального роста в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, статистика

Я, по всей видимости, использую неправильный термин, так как гугл мне не помогает.

Что мне нужно научиться делать: Находить коэффициент экспоненциального роста. Есть список вроде `[4, 8, 16]` и нужно найти коэффициент (2). Только вот список не идеальный, как в моем примере - цифры могут плавать `[400, 789, 1700]` и все еще нужно найти усредненный коэффициент.

Предполагаю, что есть какой-то метод в какой-то библиотеке, но гугл мне выдает exp и число Эйлера в степени x.

Подскажите с направлением, пожалуйста.

Comment: помню - помню... было такое в универе. построение кривой по трем точкам..)

Answer (score 1):

Можно логарифмировать элементы списка и построить приближение результата прямой, например, с помощью метода наименьших квадратов.

Коэффициент наклона прямой (a в y=ax+b) - соответствует "коэффициенту экспоненциального роста."

Модель данных

```
y = B * A^x
ln(y) = ln(B) + x * ln(A) = b + a * x
```

Подогнав  последнее, найдём `а`, а из него `A = Exp(a)`

---

Если в списке реально 3 значения - достаточно поделить второе на первое, а третье на второе, и взять среднее из этих отношений.

Comment: Три значения только для примера. Определенного списка нет, это скорее процесс обучения.
Капну в метод наименьших квадратов, спасибо

Comment: Тогда то, что в начале написано, подойдёт.

Comment: Еще момент. Коэффициент линии регрессии не будет тем же коэффициентом? (метод одномерного регрессионного анализа)

Comment: заменять экспоненциальный коэфицент на линейный.... мне кажется что-то тут не то.

Comment: @eri  Описал формулами

Comment: Во, так понятнее стало, если без смещения, то по 2м точкам можно строить.

Comment: Вот считаешь парами y1-y2 , y2-y3, y1-y3  и если коэфиценты не сошлись - то график смещён а значит система из трех уровнений ждет)

Comment: @eri Автор написал, что длина списка произвольная, 3 только как пример.

Comment: да это понятно, статистика ж, а не математика. экспонента строится по 3м точкам, остальные точки для расчёта отклонения. в подобной лабе как-раз считали выборками по 3 точки. края и одна в середине, потом края двигаешь... там по условию выкидыеются вбросы. вашу формулу я бы чуток доработал.

все 3 точки нужно сместить в y(0) = 1

Comment: проще говоря [400-399, 789-399, 1700-399] надо сделать чтоб найти  A

Answer (score 0):

Тут похоже имелось ввиду построить график

```
y=a*С^(k*x)+b
```

Надо найти С. Чтоб найти подходящюю кривую аналитически составляют систему из 3х уравнений, надо ещё координату x знать

```
400 = a*exp(k*1)+b
789 = a*exp(k*2)+b
1700 = a*exp(k*3)+b
```

делим на а и логарифмируем

```
   ln((400-b)/a) = k*1
   ....
```

k вносим под логорифм

```
   ((400-b)/a)^(1/k) = 0

   ...
```

дальше замена переменных, приведение к нормальному виду и дальше не помню - надо загуглить...)

Вот Вам похоже эту систему уравнений надо решить численными методами...

[Во чтото похожее](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/metod-chislennogo-resheniya-nekotorogo-klassa-sistem-eksponentsialnyh-uravneniy-s-ogranicheniyami-dlya-neizvestnyh-v-vide-neravenstv/viewer) , но не то что я пытаюсь вспомнить

В тех преобразованиях сводится к логарифму=1, поэтому мантиса (ну  e в экспоненте как называется..) может быть и не числом Эйлера, а ещё одним коэфицентом. который легко вычисляется когда найдете a,b,k

Comment: Вот численными методами тоже решали, не помню уж...